# How to create a stub and use it in the google test instead the original class?

Tags: c++, googletest, stub

I'm trying to create a stub in order to test some methods easier. I have a class, Animal, and I want to test the method run from my class, but it depends on some other method, let's say choseAnimal which returns the name of the animal and is placed in another class called Choice. Assume that I have a different folder for each of the 2 classes:

- folder1 which contains the Animal class and a subfolder for the google tests like below:

*Animal.hpp:*

```
#include "Choice";
...
namespace sth
{
    class Animal
    {
        public:
        void run();

        private:
        std::shared_ptr<abc::Choice> choice;
        ...
    }
}
```

*Animal.cpp:*

```
#include "Animal.hpp"
namespace sth
{
...
    void Animal::run()
    {
        if(choice->chooseAnimal().empty())
        {
            printf("no animal");
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

*Choice.hpp:* (the overwritten class)

```
#ifndef MOCKCHOICE_HPP_
#define MOCKCHOICE_HPP_
namespace abc
{
    ...
    std::string choseAnimal()
    {
        return this->animal_name;
    }

    private:
    std::string animal_name{""};
}
```

- test subfolder:

*Animal_UT.hpp:*

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "Choice.hpp"

namespace sth
{
    class TestAnimal : public ::testing::Test
    {
        public:
        Animal animal;
        abc::Choice choice;
    };
}
```

*Animal_UT.cpp:*

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "Animal_UT.hpp"

namespace abc
{
    TEST_F(TestAnimal, testRun)
    {
        choice.setAnimalName("dog");
        animal.run();
        EXPECT_EQ("dog", choice.choseAnimal());
    }
}
```

- foleder2 which contains the Choie class and some other classes:

*Choice.hpp:*

```
#ifndef CHOICE_HPP_
#define CHOICE_HPP_
namespace abc
{
    class Choice
    {
        public:
        std::string choseAnimal();
    }
    ...
}
```

*Choice.cpp:*

```
namespace abc
{
    ...
    std::string choseAnimal()
    {
        ...
        // something more complex here
        ...
        return this->animal_name;
    }

    private:
    std::string animal_name{""};
}
```

I have some CMakeLists for each folder/subfolder and no reference to the origial Choice.hpp in the cmake corresponding to the test subfolder.

**I don't understand why it takes my original class instead of the ovrwritten one inside the test.**

P.S. You might think why I need to do such a test when I can simply set the expectations on the methods from the Choice class, but I just need to see on the coverage that the run method behaves as I expect. (the stub is used to simplify the origal class here) :)

Comment: Are you actually asking about _Mocks_? Google Mocks might be helpful to realize such, and integrates seamlessly with Google test sites.

Comment: class Animal without baseclass but an overridden function doesnt make sense. You need an abstract baseclass somewhere and use dependency injection to hookup mock to the code under test.

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes you are right, I tried to summarize a more complex code, with many classes, with an easier example and I forgot to update that overridden function to make sense in my example. Sorry, now I updated it.